# Edit embed description with discord buttons using Discord py

Tags: python, api, discord.py, discord-interactions

I want to make a button (discord interactions 3.0.2/discord components) for my help command for my discord bot. The help command is basically a list commands with different categories it is also a embed message. I wanted to make a button where it can switch categories (Means that it switches/edits the discord embed message description.) I wanted to make a feature where the user can press the <- button to get back to the last category and -> for the next category of commands. They are not all in one message, the next category will appear and edit the embed message if someone presses the <- and -> buttons. Here is my code:

```
basiccommand = '''
.ping to ping the bot
.8ball ask the bot a question
'''

@commands.command()
    async def cmds2(self, ctx):
        HelpEmbed = discord.Embed(title = 'List of commands', description = basiccommand, color = discord.Colour.red())
        HelpEmbed.set_footer(text=f'{self.client.user.name} is still in developement.')
        await ctx.send(embed = HelpEmbed, components[[Button(style=1, label=label)]])
```

If you know how to edit the embed message when someone clicks on a button it will be much appreciated if you share it. I will use this as future reference, thanks.

Comment: Are you using version 4.0.0 of discord-interactions?

Comment: Yes, any version.

Comment: What version are you using? Version 4 of discord-interactions was recently released, and changes a lot of things, so it is important to know what version exactly you are using.

Comment: I am using Version 3.0.2, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dinteractions-Paginator](https://github.com/JUGADOR123/dinteractions-Paginator/) which basically makes exactly what you want, a simple to setup paginator